# VKontakte API Confusion

Tags: c#, vb.net

VK (VKontakte) API Get token then Attempt to send a request of searching audio in VK. I get an xml string of the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response list="true">
    <count>1</count>
    <audio>
        <aid>1</aid>
        <owner_id>100</Owner_id>
        <artist>and in official VKontakte applications</artist>
        <title>Audio is available on vk.com</title>
        <duration>25</duration>
        <url>https://vk.com/mp3/audio_api_unavailable.mp3</url>
    </audio>
</response>
```

I am using the below uri and request to get info.  However I am not sure what the xml is trying to tell me.  Documentation of the URI is here on this link for Requests.

https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

I am suing a standalone type application.

```
xmlDoc.Load("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.search.xml?q=" + TextBox1.Text + "?count=50&access_token=" + Form2.Token)
```

As I say again any advice or correction of my ways would be nice IF I am messing up somewhere. I have a feeling it is my parameters in

```
/method/audio.search.xml?q=" + TextBox1.Text + "?count=50&access_token=" + Form2.Token
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VKontakte have disabled their API for music.
You cannot use it anymore.

Whatever you try to request, you will always get this response which tells exactly what I say:

> Audio is available on vk.com
>   and in official VKontakte applications

If you open the provided link:

https://vk.com/mp3/audio_api_unavailable.mp3

then you will listen to the same thing, but with a nice music in background.

It was made after introduction of new VK music system with new player, as an act of official application promotion and counter-piracy measures. All other unofficial applications (like Melody, VKPlaylist, Color Player etc.) have stopped working too.

Comment: I am trying to up vote you ,but I do not have enough reputation currently. Do you mind if I ask you more questions? Also thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @ComSciDevGuy Never mind about upvoting :) It's ok. If it helped you, you can simply mark it as accepted answer. I don't mind if you ask more questions, but ask it at StackOverflow, so that other community can help you too and your questions can help other people who have the same problem.

Comment: I was finally able to upvote as I have enough to do so. Many years later, I thank you for helping guide me. Thank you so much!